# From table to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I go about creating the following table in tikz?

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 1} & Inner index 1.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & Inner index 1.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 2} & Inner index 2.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & Inner index 2.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule
            \multirow{16}{*}{Outer index 3} &  Inner index 3.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.3 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.4 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.5 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.6 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Could you please explain *why* you want to redraw the table in Ti*k*Z?

Comment: Thanks, @marmot I've been told that it allows for greater freedom, and since I'm having trouble doing things like vertically centering the first two columns, I thought I'd give this a try.

Comment: I would like to argue that using something like `makecell` will make it much more straightforward to vertically center the stuff. Of course, there are things for which you may want to use Ti*k*Z but IMHO not for that.

Comment: @marmot Wishing I had this in TikZ now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480602/saving-table-as-png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the effort you need for creating such tables in `tabular` or `tabularx` is 10, the effort you need for creating them in Ti*k*Z or any other drawing packages is at least 100. Anyway this is your table in a Ti*k*Z version.

> **Note:** Customizing it is a very hard problem IMHO, because you will probably have to break all loops... Therefore, please make tables in a usual way!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\innersep{.3333em}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={line width=0pt,text centered}]
\node[minimum height=6*\baselineskip+2*\innersep] (c1-r1) {Output index 1}; % The origin
\draw (c1-r1.south) node[below,minimum height=6*\baselineskip+2*\innersep] (c1-r2) {Output index 2};
\draw (c1-r2.south) node[below,minimum height=18*\baselineskip+6*\innersep] (c1-r3) {Output index 3};
\foreach \i in {1,2} {
    \draw (c1-r\i.north east) node[below right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip+\innersep] (c2-r\i-1) {Inner index \i.1};
    \draw (c1-r\i.south east) node[above right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip+\innersep] (c2-r\i-2) {Inner index \i.2};
    \foreach \j/\k in {2/3,3/4} {
        \draw (c\j-r\i-1.east) node[right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip-\innersep,text width=4cm,align=left] (c\k-r\i-1) {Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.};
        \draw (c\j-r\i-2.east) node[right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip-\innersep,text width=4cm,align=left] (c\k-r\i-2) {Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.};
    }
}
\draw (c1-r3.north east) node[below right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip+\innersep] (c2-r3-1) {Inner index 3.1};
\foreach \i/\j in {2/3,3/4} {
    \draw (c\i-r3-1.east) node[right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip-\innersep,text width=4cm,align=left] (c\j-r3-1) {Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.};
}
\foreach \i/\j in {2/1,3/2,4/3,5/4,6/5} {
    \draw (c2-r3-\j.south) node[below,minimum height=3*\baselineskip+\innersep] (c2-r3-\i) {Inner index 3.\i};
    \draw (c2-r3-\i.east) node[right,minimum height=3*\baselineskip+\innersep,text width=8cm+2*\innersep,align=left] (c3-r3-\i) {Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.};
}
% Lines
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} \draw (c1-r\i.north west)--(c4-r\i-1.north east);
\draw (c1-r3.south west)--(c3-r3-6.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh labels-programming-mode activated <3.

Comment: Hence, "Ti*k*Z learning = 10*(Normal learning)"? :) (fixed big typo)

Comment: @manooooh No. It is normal_way = 10 x strange_way :) (rearranged for correct order :))

Comment: To learn about matrices in Ti*k*Z I need 10 times more of learning a normal matrix.