# Saving table as PNG

Tags: png

I'd like to save the following table as png. I've tried [this](http://www.nongnu.org/dvipng/dvipng_3.html#Basic-usage) and using the Linux program convert, but both saved the whole page instead of just the table. I want to save just the table as png.

How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{78, 126, 222}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\rowcolors{1}{myblue}{}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\cellcolor{white}} c >{\cellcolor{white}}c>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            & Inner index 1.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 1} & Inner index 1.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule
             & Inner index 2.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 2} & Inner index 2.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule& Inner index 3.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.3 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 3}&Inner index 3.4 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.5 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.6 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Produce the PDF, open it with Photoshop and then save it as the format of PNG.

Comment: Even if I took your suggestion seriously, it doesn't address the issue of it saving the whole page. @Kuttens

Comment: remove the `table` environment and just have the tabular, and use `standalone` class not `article` and  the page will be resized to the table,  the class has options to auto-generate the image formats as well

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Close! That made me loose the bottom line of the table. Otherwise, if you were to answer with that, I would accept it. Can you find a solution to this and answer, please?

Comment: too late to check now but I think you will find the class has some options to add a bit of white space padding before it clips, too late to check now, feel free to self answer if you get something working

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed that and other issue that I had missed at first with `\documentclass[border={0pt 40pt 40pt 0pt}]{standalone}`. Thanks. Would you like to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a page sized to the content using the `standalone` class something like

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 40pt 40pt 0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{78, 126, 222}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\cellcolor{white}} c >{\cellcolor{white}}c>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            & Inner index 1.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 1} & Inner index 1.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule
             & Inner index 2.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 2} & Inner index 2.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule& Inner index 3.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.3 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \multirow{-2}{*}{Outer index 3}&Inner index 3.4 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.5 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            &Inner index 3.6 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

If you add `png`:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 40pt 40pt 0pt},png]{standalone}
```

and run `pdflatex` with `--shell-escape` then it will automatically use imagemagic `convert` in the background and directly produce a PNG image rather than PDF outpuput.